# Flexible key structure for JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm interested in creating a JSON Schema (to conform to OpenAPI spec, which requires JSON Schema for payload docs) that models a structure that looks like this:

```json
{
  "top-level-1": {
    "mid-level-1.1": "value1.1",
    "mid-level-1.2": "value1.2"
  },
  "top-level-2": {
    "mid-level-2.1": "value2.1"
  }
}
```

such that there can be any number of "top-level" elements, and any number of "mid-level" elements, but the structure is exactly as seen.

The closest I can get find with JSON Schema editors is something that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "top-level-1",
    "values": [
      {
        "name":"mid-level-1.1",
        "content":"value1.1"
      }, ...
]
```

Is there a way to specify "any string for a key" kind of structure?

Comment: @Fattie I take issue with your whole premise, which is that "anyone who asks a question is first an idiot, even if I don't understand the constraints under which they were working.

Comment: Paul, writing like this: *"Which is so tedious I don't even want to type it all out."* officially opens the floodgates to comedy, sarcasm and bluntness in replies and comments. I'm afraid that's how it goes.